# Star-sky при помощи canvas, помощь в оптимизации

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Задался идеей написать звездное(анимированое) небо на canvas, по идее все получилось...но когда добавил как фон, сайт начал работать с тормозами, скорей всего я где-то накосячил с кодом отрисовки и анимации.

Проверял на OC - windows 7(64) в Firefox 61.0 - подвисает, Chrome 67.0.3396.99 - тоже подвисает, но не так заметно.

Прошу помощи у понимающих. Подскажите, что переписать/дописать, где накосячил, или ваш ответ. Спасибо.

Ссылка на сайт(LP) к которому прилепил эту анимацию [>Сайт здесь<](https://viktor-hordynskyi.github.io/).
И на всякий случай, ссылка отдельно на анимацию [>Codepen<](https://codepen.io/Morpi/pen/XYopez)

```js
var c = document.getElementById('star-sky');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var x = c.width = window.innerWidth;
var y = c.height = window.innerHeight;
var nStar = Math.round((x + y) / 5);
var randomSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

var stars = [];

function createStars() {
  'use strict';
  stars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= nStar; i++) {
    stars.push({
      x: Math.random() * x,
      y: Math.random() * y,
      o: Math.random(),
      r: Math.random(),
      s: 0.02,
    })
    if (randomSize > .1) {
      ctx.shadowBlur = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15));
      ctx.shadowColor = "white";
    }
  }
}

function drawing() {
  'use strict';
  requestAnimationFrame(drawing);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  for (var i = 0; i <= nStar; i++) {
    var e = stars[i];
    if (e.o > 1 || e.o < 0) {
      e.s = -e.s;
    }
    e.o += e.s;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + e.o + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  createStars();
  drawing();
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#star-sky {
  background: linear-gradient(#00111e 30%, #033d5e);
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="star-sky"></canvas>
```

Comment: Выглядит вроде бы нормально. Что вы понимаете под "сайт начал работать с тормозами"?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, На сайте есть анимации (картинок, текста) и когда я добавил star-sky они начали подгружаться с тормозами, забил упомянуть, это очень заметно в firefox, в chrome не так бросаеться в галаза, возможно в этом причина, что для разных браузеров должна быть добавлена какая то оптимизация?

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос - это важно. С указанием версии браузера и ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на плохую оптимизацию работы с `canvas` в FF.

Если Chrome выдает 60fps, то мозила 14fps.

Скорость зависит напрямую от количества "звезд". При 50 штук уже не тормозит)

```js
var c = document.getElementById('star-sky');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var x = c.width = window.innerWidth;
var y = c.height = window.innerHeight;
var nStar = Math.round((x + y) / 5);
var randomSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

var stars = [];

var fps = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(fps);
  fps = 0;
}, 1000);

function createStars() {
  'use strict';
  stars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= nStar; i++) {
    stars.push({
      x: Math.random() * x,
      y: Math.random() * y,
      o: Math.random(),
      r: Math.random(),
      s: 0.02,
    })
    if (randomSize > .1) {
      ctx.shadowBlur = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15));
      ctx.shadowColor = "white";
    }
  }
}

function drawing() {
  'use strict';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  fps++;
  for (var i = 0; i <= nStar; i++) {
    var e = stars[i];
    if (e.o > 1 || e.o < 0) {
      e.s = -e.s;
    }
    e.o += e.s;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + e.o + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawing);
}
window.onload = function() {
  createStars();
  drawing();
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#star-sky {
  background: linear-gradient(#00111e 30%, #033d5e);
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="star-sky"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и  совет с проверкой фпс, я об этом даже не подумал, теперь можно посмотреть что нагружает фпс при работе star-sky

Comment: Поскольку скорость работы напрямую зависит от количества звезд, то ясно долго работает отрисовка одной звезды.

Comment: А понял, попробую тогда сам еще поковырять код отрисовки звезды, если что то получиться, выложу сюда. Спасибо еще раз.